# Calling context and lexical scoping

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code.I’m not sure I completely understand lexical scoping, but, unless I’m misinterpreting everything I’ve been reading, an inner function can only reference outer variables that have been declared  in the same context.

```js
let a = 7;

function test() {
  return a;
}

function test2() {
  let a = 5;
  return test()
}

console.log(test2())
```

In other words, what matters is where such functions are born and NOT where they are called, which, in the case of my example code above, means that the variable “a” that test returns is not the same as the variable “a” declared and assigned the value of 5 in test2. It’s as if the “a” in test2 were foreign to test.
Am I on the right track or is there something I’m missing?

Comment: scope of `a = 5` is insde test2(), outside always you get `7` with `let`

Comment: so your question is if you are missing something? you are not. I am not sure if this is an upvote worthy answer tho.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be on the right track.

Variables defined with `let` are local to whatever scope they are defined in, either the global scope or a function or a block inside a function. Code in a function or block can "see" variables declared within the same function or block, or variables in an outer scope such as an enclosing function or the global scope.

Your code has two distinct variables that happen to share the same name, `a`. Each `let` statement creates a brand new variable, at whatever scope the `let` statement appears in.

Because your two `a` variables are actually different and unrelated variables, we could rename them to have two different names, and the code will work the same. I will use `global_a` for one of them and `test2_a` for the other:

```
let global_a = 7;

function test() {
  return global_a; 
}

function test2() {
  let test2_a = 5;
  return test()
}

console.log(test2())
```

Now when you look at the code, you can see that `test()` only uses `global_a`. It doesn't even try to use `test2_a`. And in the `test2()` function, you can see that the `test2_a` variable is only assigned but never used!

Note that variables defined with `var` follow basically the same rules, except that inner blocks inside a function (like an `if` statement with curly braces) don't count. `var` only follows function scope and ignores blocks inside a function.